# How to get max string from objects of array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

i need to get length of string by two property of bjects.

data:

```
[ { 
   Country Code  : 'CZ',
   Country       : 'El Salvador'
},{ 
   Country Code  : 'SVY',
   Country       : 'Czech'
} ]
```

how to get 'Country: 'El Salvador' and Country Code: 'SVY'

Comment: What did you try? You just need to iterate the array.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the string that has the max length across all objects in that array for that property only?

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of each in your object literal, use `.length` inside a loop as below

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var countryLen = data[i].country.length; //11 5
    var countryCodeLen = data[i].countryCode.length; //2 3
}
```

If however, you are trying to return the longest string in your object, see below

```
var maxLen = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function (o) { return o.countryCode.length }));
```

For more information on `.map()` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: `maxLen` is not the longest string, it's the length of the longest string -- see reduce as in my answer

Comment: Quite right - I have misunderstood @axon's question

Answer (score 0):

The following is a solution that uses `reduce`; note that all objects in `arr` must contain the property `propName`.

```
let longestStr = (arr, prop) =>
    arr.reduce( (p,c) => p.length > c[prop].length ? p : c[prop] , '' )
```

`longestStr` is a function which takes an array `arr` and a property name `prop`, which should be a string.  For an in-depth discussion of how `reduce` works, I would recommend the excellent [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context for *why* or *how* this code solves the problem will improve this answer's long-term value.